How can I specify to connect remaining dots (skip null values) in Apache ECharts?
I'm testing Apache ECharts and I was wondering if it's possible to achieve following result. This is my option object
option = {
  legend: {
    data: ['A', 'B']
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: [
      '1.2.0 (01.2024)',
      '1.3.0 (02.2024))',
      '1.4.0 (03.2024)'
    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    interval: 10
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'A',
      type: 'line',
      data: [65, 60, 50]
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      type: 'line',
      data: [60, null, 55]
    }
  ]
}

and this is what I'm getting

and this is what I'd like to achieve

So basically I'd like the chart to connect all the dots it has, without leaving any holes. Is it possible?

yes, it's possible, add connectNulls:true to second line series
